# JavaScript challenge: Create an average-calculating function using recursion?

Tags: javascript

I've had trouble writing this code. I'm supposed to make a function that can take either an array of numbers or the arguments array and calculate the average without using a `for` or `while` loop. It says I have to use recursion. How do I do this?

Comment: By asking SO to write this function? It's recursive, and it's tail-optimized already, I suppose. )

Comment: This is not a naturally recursive problem.  But here's a clue, a possible function signature: `var recursiveAverage = function(vals, curr_total, curr_count) { ...`;

Comment: Well, if it turned out to be a real question, here's my [real answer](http://jsfiddle.net/hLs7q/2/). I'm too shy to post it not in comments, though. ) But it successfully reminded me why I love Erlang, though. )

Comment: raina77ow, pattern matching is indeed a brilliant concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to finish it myself thanks to what you guys suggested. I was confused on how to go about the actual average calculation until after reading what you guys posted. If this code can be improved please tell! Thanks!

```
function mean( list, more ) {

    if ( more ) {

        list = [].slice.call( arguments );

    } else if ( !list || list[0] === undefined ) return;

    var a = list,
        b = list.length;


    return (function execute() {

        if ( !a.length ) return 0;

        return ( a.pop() / b ) + execute();

    })();

}
```

Comment: ... if you're using anonymous functions and apply like that, you probably didn't need to ask. Interesting way to do it.

Comment: I really love that twist, saving original length of array into outer variable, for the happy band of closures to feast on. Brilliant. )

Comment: ... and there's another one: using `return` to trigger the call of defined function. Verrry nice. )

Comment: Yet it can be optimized, no, really! `d` can be used as accumulator for `total`, so division will be used just once - in `if ( !c.length)` block. :P

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're familiar with recursion.

Just implement a recursive function with an index argument to keep track of where you are, and add the numbers to the same variable. Then at the end, divide by the size of your array.

Edit:
As Kranklin points out in a comment, using pop you won't even need the index argument. (You will need to store the size of the array before iterating).

Comment: Another way would be to Pop off the numbers of the array with each iteration, so no index would be required

Comment: I like the `.pop()` idea, assuming it is only used on a copy of the array that was originally passed to the function (because I'm not so keen on modifying the original parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is but by looking at it you agree to **understand it**:

http://jsfiddle.net/sparebyte/kGg9Y/1/

```
function calcAverage(nums, total, count) {
    if(isNaN(count)) {
        // First iteration: Init Params
        return calcAverage(nums, 0, nums.length);
    }
    if(nums.length) {
        // Middle itrations: Get a total
        total = nums.pop() + total;
        return calcAverage(nums, total, count)
    } else {
        // Last iteration: Find the total average
        return total / count     
    }
};
```

Comment: Although, `isNaN(undefined)` returns `true` I wouldn't write it that way. You're trying to check if the count is `undefined` so I would try `if(typeof count === 'undefined')` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
function average(set, memo, total) {
  memo || (memo = 0);
  total || (total = set.length);
  if (set.length === 0) return memo / total;
  return average(set.slice(1, set.length), (memo + set[0]), total);
}
```

You call it like this:

```
average([1,2,3,4]); // 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
function av(nums, i, t) {
   if (!Array.isArray(nums))
       return av([].slice.call(arguments));
   if (t === void 0){
       if (nums.length === 0)
          return;
       return av(nums, nums.length-1, 0);
   }
   t += nums[i];   
   if (i > 0)
       return av(nums, i-1, t);
   return t / nums.length;
}
```

Accepts an array of numbers, or if the first param is not an array assumes all arguments are numbers. (No error checking for non-numeric data like `av('a','x')`.) Returns `undefined` if array is empty or no params are supplied.

```
alert( av([1,2,3,4]) );   // 2.5
alert( av(1,2,3,4,5) );   // 3
```

Assumes `Array.isArray()` (or an [appropriate shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Compatibility)) is available.